# Update_Comment_meta is not defined

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am working with WordPress plugin, and I am doing following.

1. Create a new button in comments.

   ```
   <a href="magic.php?cid=<?php echo $comment_ID; ?>&pid=<?php echo $post_ID; ?>">Click here</a>
   ```
2. Now on magic.php I am calling update_comment_meta.

   ```
   $decode_str=base64_decode($_GET['en']);

   if(substr($decode_str, 0,4) != "http"){
     $decode_str = "http://".$decode_str;
   }
   if(is_numeric($_GET['cid']) && is_numeric($_GET['pid'])  ){

         update_comment_meta( $_GET['pid'] , 'pinned', $_GET['cid'] ); 

   }
   header("Location: ".$decode_str);
   ```

   ?>
3. It givens me error, update_comment_meta is not defined.

What I think is I might need to load wp-load.php, because magic.php all alone doesn't know it is a part of wordpress.

I don't want to do AJAX. I have also read loading wp-load.php within your file is not a good idea.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please add some of the code you have tried to your question?

Comment: @Red Shift Added the code.